# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I want to my program to increase the pensize of Python's turtle when the Page UP key is pressed.
I tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Control using first letter of desired action')
py=turtle.Turtle()
py.color('blue')
size=1
def front():
    py.fd(90)
def back():
    py.bk(90)
def right():
    py.rt(45)
def left():
    py.lt(45)
def increasize():
    global size
    while size>=1 and size<=20:
        py.pensize+=1
def decreasize():
    global size
    while size>=1 and size<=20:
        py.pensize-=1
wn.onkey(front,'w')
wn.onkey(back,'s')
wn.onkey(right,'d')
wn.onkey(left,'a')
wn.onkey(increasize,'Prior')
wn.onkey(decreasize,'Next')
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

But it gives an error. Full traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\program files\python3\lib\turtle.py", line 686, in eventfun
    fun()
  File "D:\Python\draw_straight_key.py", line 19, in increasize
    py.pensize+=1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\program files\python3\lib\turtle.py", line 686, in eventfun
    fun()
  File "D:\Python\draw_straight_key.py", line 23, in decreasize
    py.pensize-=1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'method' and 'int'
```

Comment: Please put your code in the body of your question.

Comment: Please also post the **full text** of the error or traceback.

Comment: pensize is a method, not a variable. Look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.pensize) and fix it yourself.

Comment: `py.pensize` is a method that *returns* an `int` - it is not an `int` itself. `py._pensize` is the value that can be incremented via `+=`. However, the underscore in the variable name indicates that it's a private variable and probably shouldn't be modified in this way.

Comment: I fixed it by `py.pensize(size+1)` but it's size increasing upto 2 and not more than that

Comment: That's because `size` is always 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the pensize method with the new size.  A method reference cannot be added to

For example, in increasize

```
size += 1
py.pensize(size)
```

Also, unless you want the size to always be one size (20), then change the while loop to an if statement

```
while size>=1 and size<=20:
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like pensize() is a method (not a variable) and needs to be called: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.pensize

Try this:

```
pensize = py.pensize()
pensize += 1
py.pensize(pensize)
```